# Is there any way for a view controller in iOS 5 to specify an image to be used in a back button on a navigation stack push over it?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have Controller A and controller B is pushed on top of it in a navigation stack. Is there anyway for controller A to specify an image (say controller A is some sort of list so it specifies a list image) and then controller B's navigation item's back button automatically shows that as the back button image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `UIBarButtonItem` and set `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` to that custom button.

[UINavigationItem class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)

Comment: I do get that, was hoping for a way to not have to set the button manuaally each time. This is analogous to the way the back button gets updated with the previous controller's title text, if any.

Comment: By "manually each time" you mean for each view controller that you want a custom icon for?  That is kind of how custom behavior has to be implemented.  If you mean each time that view controller is pushed, once it is set on the VC, as long as the VC does not get deallocated it will remain the same.

Comment: You don't have to implement the title of the previous VC showing up. I was just wondering if there's a way where you can just set a 'title image' and then have the back buttons automatically set it on the back button when the next VC gets pushed.

Comment: the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is what will display on the navigation bar to go back to that specific navigation item.  For example, if you have a view that displays a chart, and you make a back button for it that is a pie chart, when ever you push something ON TOP of the chart VC, that chart back button will display.  It is not what you are setting for the current view.

Comment: Again, I do get modifying the back button in the top most controller, was just wondering if there's a way to do it in the controller that's going to get a VC pushed onto it. From your answers it looks like you think it isn't directly possible.

Comment: What you're trying to do is exactly what I am telling you to do.  You have VC `A`, in VC `A` you set the back button, then you push VC `B` on top of it.  When VC `B` is now on top of VC `A`, the back button you set in VC A is displayed instead of the standard one.  If instead you push VC `C`, the same back button is displayed that you set in VC `A`

Comment: Ah I see where I was misunderstanding what you were saying. Looks like the answer was right under my nose - thanks :)

Comment: No problem, the whole idea can be confusing, how you're setting the back button not for the view that is currently up, but for when this is one back on the stack.